# show progress indicator when waiting for initializing app for example when authenticate users

Tags: flutter, dart

There is application that login or register users and after authenticate them, navigate them to main page.

In login and register processes app should connect to server and read data from database so it can take some time to response ,in the while user should wait.
This application need an splash screen to show for 2 second ([perfect splash guideline](https://uxdesign.cc/building-the-perfect-splash-screen-46e080395f06)), after that either it navigate to main page or show progress indicator or show friendly error like "check your internet connection" with a retry button in snackbar.
What widgets do you recommend for this purpose?

User run the app then splash screen shows... now if it take more than 2 second and splash animation end it should show progress indicator otherwise navigate user to main page.
any tip might help.
Thanks community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you call a web service you should write a Function that returns Future like below.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
...
Future<ServerResponse> Login() async {
  final lUrl = '$baseUrl/api...';
  final lResponse = await this.httpClient.get(lUrl);
  if (lResponse.statusCode != 200) {
    return Future.error('error getting locationId for city');
  }

  final lJson = jsonDecode(lResponse.body) as List;
  return Future.value(lJson);
}
```

**so when you want to use this function you have 2 way**

1. first use stateless widget

if you have a StateLess widget you can use https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

2. use stetefull widget

if you have a statefull widget ... define `isLoading = true` in your widget and
you can call the function in initState like below

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    login().then((value) {
      print("we Got data !! ");
      isLoading = false;
      setState(() {});
    },onError: (msg){
      // handle error here
      print(msg.toString());
    });
  }
```

and in you build use from `isloading` like below

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLoading ? CircularProgressIndicator() : MyWidget()
 )}
```

Comment: prefer to use FutureBuilder because it handle easily future and build method and can implement splash screen or other widgets like ProgressIndicatorBar after flutter engine get started, befor that its better to use packages like [this native dart splash screen](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash)

Answer (score 1):

In the body, make it a stack. Let the first child be your main widget, then the next be a center widget with its child being a "Loading widget" like this

```
Stack(
 children:[Container(),
  Center(
   child:isLoading?Loading():Container()   
)]
)
```

Define an isLoading boolean variable and declare it false. Whenever you have to pause to authenticate, write it like this

```
setState((){
isLoading = true
})
await {Your authentication stuff}
setState((){
isLoading = false
})
```

And the loading widget can be your splash screen.